# Laravel require at least one field

Tags: validation, laravel, rules

I'm building a form . there is 3 specific text filed that at least one of them should be filled by the user. how may i implement it with Laravel validation rules?

```
 //dd($request)

 array:6 [▼
 "_token" => "o5td5RMv2EQ5mA7LqXpyMXCKIu7L78BfrRSEU1se"
"skill_id" => "6"
 "plan_id" => "1"
 //at least one of below fields should be filled
 "context" => ""
 "link" => ""
 "desired_date" => ""
 ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

**required_without_all:foo,bar,...**

In this the field under validation must be present only when all of the other specified fields are not present.

```
$rules = array(
    'skill_id' => 'required_without_all:plan_id,context,link',
    'plan_id' => 'required_without_all:skill_id,context,link',
);
```

**OR**

You can use the `required_unless` rule: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-required-unless

**required_unless:anotherfield,value,...**

IN this case, the field under validation must be present unless the anotherfield field is equal to any value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [required_without_all](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-required-without-all)

```
$rules = array(
    'context' => 'required_without_all:link,desired_date',
    'link' => 'required_without_all:context,desired_date',
    'desired_date' => 'required_without_all:context,link',
);
```